# How to delete documents from Elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I can't find any example of deleting documents from `Elasticsearch` in Python. What I've seen by now - is definition of `delete` and `delete_by_query` functions. But for some reason [documentation](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.delete_by_query) does not provide even a  microscopic example of using these functions. The single list of parameters does not tell me too much, if I do not know how to correctly feed them into the function call. So, lets say, I've just inserted one new doc like so:

```
doc = {'name':'Jacobian'}
db.index(index="reestr",doc_type="some_type",body=doc)
```

Who in the world knows how can I now delete this document using `delete` and `delete_by_query` ?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Since you are not giving a document id while indexing your document, you have to get the auto-generated document id from the return value and delete according to the id. Or you can define the id yourself, try the following:

```
 db.index(index="reestr",doc_type="some_type",id=1919, body=doc)

 db.delete(index="reestr",doc_type="some_type",id=1919)
```

In the other case, you need to look into return value;

```
 r = db.index(index="reestr",doc_type="some_type", body=doc)
 # r = {u'_type': u'some_type', u'_id': u'AU36zuFq-fzpr_HkJSkT', u'created': True, u'_version': 1, u'_index': u'reestr'}

 db.delete(index="reestr",doc_type="some_type",id=r['_id'])
```

Another example for delete_by_query. Let's say after adding several documents with name='Jacobian', run the following to delete all documents with name='Jacobian':

```
 db.delete_by_query(index='reestr',doc_type='some_type', q={'name': 'Jacobian'})
```

Comment: Can you, please, elaborate a bit more? Especially, I'm interested in the case when I do not know `id` (id=1919 in your example) beforehand. I ask this because I need to do bulk deletion.

Comment: And, as I asked, an example of `delete_by_query` will also be greatly appreciated by me and other newbies.

Comment: Two tiny examples of how to delete all docs where doc_type="some_type" and where doc.name = "John" wil worth +100500 of reputation =)

Comment: Then you need to take a look into the return value from .index() method. I have updated the answer to cover this case. It's quite simple, r['_id'] is the auto-generated id number you're looking for. :)

Comment: Thank you, sir! Great answer that will be helpful to future generations of programmers =)

Comment: instead of "q" parameter, you have to provide "body" parameter now
`body={
                    'query': {
                        'term': {
                            'name': 'Jacobian'
                        }
                    }
                }`

Answer (score 13):

The Delete-By-Query API was removed from the ES core in version 2 for several reasons. This function became a plugin. You can look for more details here:

[Why Delete-By-Query is a plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.0/delete-by-query-plugin-reason.html)

[Delete By Query Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/plugins-delete-by-query.html)

Because I didn't want to add another dependency (because I need this later to run in a docker image) I wrote an own function solving this problem. My solution is to search for all quotes with the specified index and type. After that I remove them using the Bulk API:

```
def delete_es_type(es, index, type_):
    try:
        count = es.count(index, type_)['count']
        response = es.search(
            index=index,
            filter_path=["hits.hits._id"],
            body={"size": count, "query": {"filtered" : {"filter" : {
                  "type" : {"value": type_ }}}}})
        ids = [x["_id"] for x in response["hits"]["hits"]]
        if len(ids) > 0:
            return
        bulk_body = [
            '{{"delete": {{"_index": "{}", "_type": "{}", "_id": "{}"}}}}'
            .format(index, type_, x) for x in ids]
        es.bulk('\n'.join(bulk_body))
        # es.indices.flush_synced([index])
    except elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError as ex:
        print("Elasticsearch error: " + ex.error)
        raise ex
```

I hope that helps future googlers ;)

Comment: Looks like delete by query has been reinstated, and the plugin now killed of. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/docs-delete-by-query.html

Answer (score 5):

One can also do something like this:

```
def delete_by_ids(index, ids):
    query = {"query": {"terms": {"_id": ids}}}
    res = es.delete_by_query(index=index, body=query)
    pprint(res)

# Pass index and list of id that you want to delete.
delete_by_ids('my_index', ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'])
```

Which will perform the delete operation on bulk data

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post while searching for a way to delete a document on ElasticSearch using their Python library, ElasticSearch-DSL.

In case it helps anyone, this part of their documentation describes the document lifecycle.
https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html#document-life-cycle

And at the end of it, it details how to delete a document:

> To delete a document just call its delete method:
>
> ```
> first = Post.get(id=42)
> first.delete()
> ```

Hope that helps